# Linq to sql between List and Comma separated string

Tags: c#, linq, list

I Have one list and one comma separated column value.

```
lst.Add("Beauty");
lst.Add("Services");
lst.Add("Others");
```

And Column value is like

```
Beauty,Services
Service,Others
Beauty,Others
Other,Services
Other
Beauty, Food
Food
```

Now I Want all those rows which contains any list item.

Output result is

```
Beauty,Services
Service,Others
Beauty,Others
Other,Services
Other
Beauty, Food
```

**First Edit**

These comma separated values are one of my table's one column value.
I need to check against that column.

Comment: Its a bit unclear to me what sort of data structure(s) you are using. Do you mean that you have a .csv file and want to compare it against the list, or have you loaded the comma seperated values into some sort of data structure already?

Comment: @SeanThoman I think that he is getting the rows from a database just from it being asked as Linq2Sql

Comment: @msarchet I guess so. It's just confusing because Linq-to-SQL doesn't usually produce comma seperated values, as far as I know. Wouldn't he just have a DataTable or some domain object?

Comment: @Sean it could if he has them as strings in a database

Comment: Thanks Guys for your comments. Actually this values are from one table's One column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can figure out how to get the RowCollection

```
RowCollection.Where(row => row.Split(",").ToList().Where(x => list.Contains(x)).Any()).ToList();
```

will evaluate to true if the row contains a value from the list.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
List<string> lst = ....; // your list of strings

string[] somecolumnvalues = new string[] { "", "",... }; // your columvalues

var Result = from l in lst from c in somecolumnsvalues where c.Contains (l) select c;
```